# PHP htaccess rewrite rules with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a running service that lets my user choose their own URL address (example: http://hsdfhdfghfh.com/theUserURL)

Now I'm going to put my front site on a wordpress but keep my app running along-side with it.

Now for the problem, i've set a rule in htaccess to forward my users url to their page, but wordpress also needs the same rule in order to make pretty URL (permalink).

Here is my htaccess with my code and the code that wordpress injected. Currently only my redirect is working, how can I make them both work together?
Can I add a code in my php file that gets the URLs and if it has no entries I throw it to wordpress to show?

This is my htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./url.php?w=$1

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And this is my php (url.php) file that handles the redirects:

```
<?php

session_start();

$url_name = $_GET['w'];


include ('init.php');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM urls WHERE url='$url_name'");  
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$query_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if($num_rows == 0){

    include($theurl.'/404.php');
    exit();
}


$_SESSION['url_id'] = $query_result['url_id'];

?>

..Shows the rest of the page for the user with the specified url_id session...
```

Maybe instead of showing the 404.php page I could transfer the entered URL to wordpress somehow?

Cheers!

Comment: Hey Prix, the user is setting the URL in my app domain.com/UserURL. Is there no way to transfer the entered URL to wordpress from a php file outside of wordpress?

Comment: As I wrote on the top, I have 2 sites working together on the same page, Wordpress and my web app. Wordpress is used for the selling site and the other is the app itself. The User's URL is handles by my Webapp.    I solved this by replacing the 404.php include with the following:  include($theurl.'/index.php');
Wordpress handles the redirects if I found no URL in my DB. Does someone see something wrong with this method?

Comment: Glad you found a solution but looking at your `.htaccess` you're sure to have issues to come, GL. Basically `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` is a catch-all and `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./url.php?w=$1` is also a catch-all were both have the same conditions unless they are in different document root one will steal from another and may cause it to fail.

Comment: So now if I just include the index file of wordpress in my redirect I can loose the wordpress rules in htaccess right?

Comment: Like I said I don't know how your app is working and you haven't provide any details that show it so I can say how it will behave. All you have showed was a URL with no real example of how your app works against how your blog is at  the moment nor if you have different domains or sub domain on different root folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying different approaches and trying to manipulate using .htaccess I realized that this process is very bad for loading times and overloading the server.

I ended up moving Laravel to a subdomain :/

Don't try to put Wordpress and Laravel together on the same domain unless you really want to tweak wordpress to the core.